# Installing python module pyexiv2 on CentOS?

Tags: centos, software-installation, python

I downloaded the latest pyexiv2 files: pyexiv2-0.3.2.tar.bz2 and I looked at the README file which said:

```
To build and install the library, while in the top-level directory
(e.g. '~/dev/pyexiv2', which should contain a file named 'SConstruct'),
run the following commands:

 $ scons
 $ scons install # as administrator, e.g. `sudo scons install`

The result of the build is a dynamic library, libexiv2python.so, in the build/
directory. This is the low-level binding. It is in turn used in a higher level
module, pyexiv2.
The install command installs the two modules in your site-specific directory for
Python modules (e.g. '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/' on Linux).
```

I did exactly this, `su` (now running as root)

`cp -r 'pyexiv2-0.3.2' ~`

Then ran: `scons`

It said:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
o build/exiv2wrapper.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 src/exiv2wrapper.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build/exiv2wrapper_python.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 src/exiv2wrapper_python.cpp
sh: o: command not found
o build/libexiv2python.so -shared build/exiv2wrapper.os build/exiv2wrapper_python.os -lboost_python -lexiv2
sh: o: command not found
scons: done building targets.
```

Any ideas where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is broken in your scons installation or you don't have g++ installed. Working from the same source, scons reports:

```
g++ -o build/exiv2wrapper.os -c -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 src/exiv2wrapper.cpp
…
```

for me. I'd look in `/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/g++.py` or even just try

```
$ g++ --version
```

to see where the error is. If g++ is not installed, install it. If scons support files are broken, it is probably easier to reinstall it than debug it.

Comment: Thanks I did need g++ installed. It didn't fix my issue but It narrows down my search. Thanks. I just used: yum install gcc-c++